# How to redirect NGINX to a websocket

Tags: nginx, websocket, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

1. NGINX - sitting on 10.10.10.1
2. LAMP - sitting on 172.168.1.1 , has phpwebsockets.This listens on http://172.168.1.1:8080 and having ws folder at http://172.168.1.1:8080/ws

Nginx supposed to forward request in this fashion.

```
 NGINX                                 --->      LAMP Websocket
```

**http**://10.10.10.1/randomstring/ --> **https**://10.10.10.1/randomstring/ --> **http**://172.168.1.1:8080

Currect /conf.d/internal.conf nginx config file is

```
server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    172.168.1.1;
    return         301 https://$host$request_uri; #redirect to self with https
    }
server {
    listen          443 ssl;
    server_name     172.168.1.1;
    root           /var/www/nginx/;
    index          index.html;
    proxy_cache one;
    location /ws {
        proxy_pass http://172.168.1.1:8080;
        # this magic is needed for WebSocket
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.168.1.1:8080;
    }
}
```

I am unable to forward to /randomstring , it works for without 'randomstring'.

Comment: Any help anyone ?

Answer (score 0):

Please add "/" at the end of proxy_pass

```
proxy_pass http://172.168.1.1:8080/;
```

Comment: But where to enter the randomstring path?